# How to avoid gc_for_alloc when I call Bitmap.createBitmap()?

Tags: java, android, performance

My call to Bitmap.createBitmap() always leads to gc_for_alloc.
Here is the code:

```
if (theFinger.isTheSaveFlag())
{
    theBackGroundBuffer.position(0);
    gl.glReadPixels(0, 0, theBackGroundWidth, theBackGroundHeight, GL10.GL_RGBA, GL10.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, theBackGroundBuffer);
    theBackGroundBuffer.position(0);
    theBackGroundBuffer.get(theBackGroundPixel);
    theBackGroundTexture.dispose();
    theBackGround.recycle();
    theBackGround = Bitmap.createBitmap(theBackGroundPixel, theBackGroundWidth, theBackGroundHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    theBackGroundTexture.load(theBackGround);
}
```

Can someone tell me why?

Comment: `GC_FOR_ALLOC` messages in logcat are normal. It's the garbage collector doing its job when memory is required for new memory allocations. What is the specific problem you're facing?

Answer (score 0):

In android it always calls garbage collector to collect and remove the unused resources from the memory that is why it prints `gc_for_alloc` message which shows that the unused resources are getting removed and allotted space for the other resources which require it.

As specially its getting called whenever you are doing operations on Images and loading the large number of images in memory which requires bit more space to load.

Comment: So there is no way to avoid the problem caused by that?

Comment: This is not problem its behavior of garbage collector of android.